# how to center text of button using css

Tags: html, css, frontend, center

I can't center the text inside the button, tried margin - 0, padding -0
html code -

```css
.del{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
    border: none;
    color: #eee;
    background-color:  rgb(187, 141, 81);
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
 <button class="del btn btn-sm" type="submit">x</button>
```

Comment: See snippet, looks centered to me, you must have some other css that is overriding what you have already

Comment: the text is already center only, have a look on this https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/a2rup8eL/